# How to show list items in columns in ASP web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Hi I am trying to show list items in bootstrap columns but this code show list in vertical straight line

```
 <div class="row">
    <% var registragionNumberList = AppCalculations.GetInstance().GetRegistrationNumber();%>

    <%       
        foreach (var item in registragionNumberList)
        {%>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <textarea> item </textarea>            
    </div>

    <%} %>
</div>
```

please review and correct.

Comment: What's the problem of your code? As I can see you will have three textarea per row. Do you want in each row to have only one text area?

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have provided works fine for me - it shows the results in three different columns so the issue isn't with the code that you have provided. I would guess that the issue is with bootstrap not being loaded correctly, do you have a script tag for bootstrap on the page?

If bootstrap is loaded and you are still seeing the issue then it might be worth seeing if there is some other styling that is causing an issue, try putting your code on an empty page with just boostrap and the code that you have put above.

Comment: ThanksI solved the issue... it was about bootstrap... Now another issue is I   need to show multiple graphs from model data the problem is.. single graph is loading but multiple graphs are not loading and the asp:Chart control stops working.. I don't know why? can you help me...

Comment: @Talha That's good. Please create another question for the new issue and mark this answer as the accepted answer for this question

Comment: You don't need any reputation to accept an answer, just to upvote: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Done and my question limit has alos been reached so I need another help from you... I am using chartControl in asp web forms. Single chart works fine but when I plot charts using foreach loop it plots only one line
<Series>
               <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Line" XValueMember="DateAndTime" YValueMembers="Average" BorderWidth="2" IsValueShownAsLabel="True"></asp:Series>
                <asp:Series Name="Series2" ChartType="Line" XValueMember="DateAndTime" YValueMembers="FuelAverage" Color="Red" BorderWidth="2" IsValueShownAsLabel="True"></asp:Series>
            </Series>